# How to send dictionary in command line as argument to VB file

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, arguments

Is it possible to call a VB.NET script
passing a dictionary as an argument
from the command line?

Comment: Yes, if you encode it as a string. Add some more details to your question to get a more helpful answer. Btw, a VB.Net program is not a script.

Comment: Be advised that the max length of a command line command is 8191 characters. If your dictionary has the potential to reach 8kb, consider passing the string data via the pipeline and receive it in your VB.NET app via stdin instead. Or you could use a JSON or XML file or something. If you prefer JSON, look into [System.Web.Script.Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Comment: You can serialize and deserialize a dictionary to an XML file, and pass the pathname to that xml document as your command line argument.